# can .net framework 4.0 app run on window Ce or windows embeded CE

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-ce

Quick summary-  can my framework 4.0 app work on windows CE or not and how i develop app for such a small screen using .C# net

Detail -I have pda(personal digital assistant) having  Microsoft  Os windows CE or windows embedded CE.and i want to develop a application for that,just like normal windows application in windows 7. pda having small touch screen(4 inch) like mobile  . is any window 7 PDA available in market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 supports development for Windows Embedded Compact 2013.[3]

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and earlier support projects for older releases of Windows CE / Windows Mobile, producing executable programs and platform images either as an emulator or attached by cable to an actual mobile device. A mobile device is not necessary to develop a CE program. The .NET Compact Framework supports a subset of the .NET Framework with projects in C#, and VB.NET, but not Managed C++. "Managed" applications employing the .NET Compact Framework also require devices with significantly larger memories (8 MB or more) while unmanaged applications can still run successfully on smaller devices. In Visual Studio 2010, the Windows Phone Developer Tools are used as an extension, allowing Windows Phone 7 apps to be designed and tested within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no, Windows CE cannot run any .NET application compiled for the desktop regardless of the framework version it was build for.  Windows CE can only run .NET Compact Framework applications, so the app and all dependencies must specifically have been compiled for the Compact Framework.  The latest version of the CF for CE 6.0 is 3.5 and to compile for CF 3.5 you must have Visual Studio 2008.

If you have all of the source for the app and its dependencies, you may be able to refactor the code to build against the CF, but my experience is that UI code is usually easier to just rewrite from the ground up that to try to back-port.  Business logic is usually pretty transferrable.

Comment: what about window embedded compact 7 or 2013 ?

Comment: No version of Windows CE/Windows Embedded Compact can run a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

> how i develop app for such a small screen using .C# net

if your device runs on Win CE 5.0 with visual studio 2005 and [Windows CE 5.0: Standard Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17310)

> Quick summary- can my framework 4.0 app work on windows C

no, because Win CE runs with Compact Framework

Comment: what about window embedded compact 7 or 2013

Answer (score 0):

You may also use .NET CF 3.9 and Visual Studio 2012 with app-builder, but this version of the Compact Framework is supported only on devices running Windows Embedded Compact 2013 and, since this release is pretty recent, it's not easy to find devices running it on the market.

Comment: No, it does not.  It's still effectively 3.5, with some runtime improvements (speed, etc) but no language improvements.